# Vertx: How to combine third party events with Standard Verticle and Worker Verticle style event send and reply approach

Tags: asynchronous, vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertx-eventbus

I am trying to solve an issue whereby I need to combine third party events with the eventBus send and reply approach that Vertx provides for Standard and Worker Verticle setups. I am not sure if what I have laid out below is necessarily the correct approach.

**Problem Statement:**

I want to have standard verticle that sends a message to a worker verticle.
The worker verticle does some preprocessing and then uses a client method provided by a third party state management lib to publish an even (in an async manner). The result of which is only whether or not the event was successfully received or not (but does not contain any further info around processing etc).

Further processing takes place when the third party state management lib receives the event(this all happens on a separate thread) and a success or failure can occur at which point another event will be published to the cluster management tools output channel.

From the output channel listener I then want to be able to use the event to somehow use the message.reply() on the worker verticle to send back a response to the standard verticle that made the original request, thereby closing the loop of the entire request lifecycle but also using the async approach that vertx is built to use.

Now I conceptually know how to do 90% of what is described here but the missing piece for me is how to coordinate the event on the output channel listener and connect this to the worker verticle so that I can trigger the message.reply.

I have looked at possibly using SharedData and Clustering that Vertx has but was wondering if there is possibly another approach.
I have put a possible example implementation but would really appreciate if anyone has any insights/thoughts into how this can be accomplished and if I am on the right track.

```
class Order(val id: String)

class OrderCommand(val order: Order) : Serializable {

    companion object {
        const val name = "CreateOrderCommand"
    }
}

class SuccessOrderEvent(val id: String) : Serializable {

    companion object {
        const val name = "OrderSuccessfulEvent"
    }
}

interface StateManagementLib {

    fun <T> send(
        value: T,
        success: Handler<AsyncResult<Int>>,
        failure: Handler<AsyncResult<Exception>>
    ) {
        val output = publish(value)
        if (output == 1) {
            success.handle(Future.succeededFuture())
        } else {
            failure.handle(Future.failedFuture("Failed"))
        }
    }

    // non-blocking
    fun <T> publish(value: T): Int // returns success/failure only
}


class WorkVerticle constructor(private val lib: StateManagementLib) : AbstractVerticle() {

    override fun start(startPromise: Promise<Void>) {
        workerHandler()
        startPromise.complete()
    }

    private fun workerHandler() {
        val consumer = vertx.eventBus().consumer<OrderCommand>(OrderCommand.name)
        consumer.handler { message: Message<OrderCommand> ->
            try {
                vertx.sharedData().getClusterWideMap<String, Message<OrderCommand>>("OrderRequest") { mapIt ->
                    if (mapIt.succeeded()) {
                        lib.send(message.body(), {
                            // The StateManagementLib successfully propagated the event so, we try and store in this map (id -> Message)
                            mapIt.result().put(message.body().order.id, message)
                        }, {
                            message.fail(400, it.result().message)
                        })
                    }
                }
               
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                message.fail(
                    HttpResponseStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.code(), "Failed to encode data."
                )
            }
        }

        // A consumer that will pick up an event that is received from the clusterTool output channel
        vertx.eventBus().addInboundInterceptor { context: DeliveryContext<SuccessOrderEvent> ->
            // Retrieve cluster map to get the previously stored message and try to respond with Message.reply
            // This should go back to the Standard Verticle that sent the message
            vertx.sharedData().getClusterWideMap<String, Message<OrderCommand>>("OrderRequest") {
                if (it.succeeded()) {
                    val id = context.message().body().id
                    val mapResult = it.result().get(id)
                    it.result().remove(id)
                    // Try and reply so the original eventloop thread can pickup and respond to calling client
                    mapResult.result().reply(id)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: worker verticles should be avoided in favour of executeBlocking btw. If you  need such async events then still trying to retrofit request/response can be difficult. The only way is to have a listener at each level that closes the loop back. I.e. return a future or promise back that on success sends back the eventbus reply

Comment: Hi @AsadAwadia  I tried using the approach of executeBlocking with a promise (overall much simpler and cleaner) but I still need to use the SharedData to store the promise and complete it at a later stage as the output channel for the statemanagement lib is a different thread and has no context as to the original call made to process the event.

Am I missing something in your reply, as with this approach I dont have any listeners involved?

Im not sure if

Comment: Yes that's the way to go. A shared data or a ConcurrentHashmap are both fine to store the promises and yeah you will need an arbitrator in between if the two places do not have context of each other. Shareddata and CHM both can be used for that

Comment: Thanks @AsadAwadia, appreciate the insights